# How Print all tabs in Adobe Reader with a single click?

Tags: printing, adobe-reader, tabs

If you have several tabs open in Adobe Reader, how can you with a single command/click print all of them at once?

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that works for me is to put all the files into a directory, then open and print one with the print settings I want.  Leaving the original file open, you can then select all the others, right-click, and print.  They'll all print using the settings from the first print.

Comment: That's actually a very cool workaround. Not many people know about the context menu print option..

Comment: its better to change print settings in system instead of adobe reader

Answer (score 1):

1. Select up to 15 files in a folder with a mouse or keyboard holding
   Shift (15 consequent files) or Ctrl (pick random files with a mouse
   holding Ctrl key)
2. Right-click on the selection area and choose
   Print. Depending on the default PDF program set as viewer the files
   will be opened and printed one by one or will be printed without
   opening.

This has been tested with Windows 10 and Adobe Reader.[image]

P.S. 15 files in the print selection is a limitation of the OS.